# Querying a query?

Tags: sql-server, database

Lets say  I have five tables named table1, table2 ... table5.
I have  already made a view/query named query1 by joining table1, 2 and 3.

Now, I want to create a view  which requires joining all the five tables. My question is, is it good to use query1 and just join table4  and  table5 into it, or is it better  to  join  the five tables one by one?

Im afraid that if  I join two views, or a view and table/s, then modifying that same view requires me to reconstruct the whole  query becauses of being  dependent to that view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want your queries to be dependent on a view, then you must ask yourself, why you are creating that view in the first place.

If your 5-table query joins `table1`, `table2` and `table3` in a way that *merely happens* to be identical to how the same tables are joined in the `query1` view but in actual fact has a completely different meaning, then, in my opinion, it would be perfectly fine *not* to use `query1` in your second view/query.

But if your second view/query is going to reproduce the same business rules that are already implemented in `query1`, then I can see absolutely no point in duplicating the code. That's partly the point of a view: by creating it, you can avoid repeating the same code if it needs to be used many times. When you alter `query1`, it would make sense for other dependent queries and/or views to alter their output accordingly.

Of course, sometimes changes in a view require changes in other queries and/or views that use it. If that's what you are concerned most about at the moment, then I suggest you invest your time into planning your views properly to reduce the possibility of such changes after your database has been in use for a long time.

So, basically, your choice is either to duplicate logic in every view to avoid their being dependent upon one another, or use your views actively as necessary but risk coming across a situation where you *have* to make a chain of changes merely because one particular view *needs* to be changed. But, again, as I said earlier, you can minimise that risk if you properly design your views *beforehand*.

Comment: The idea about planning beforehand strikes me the most. Thats the previously hidden problem I suppose to have, I think.

Comment: HOwever, if the second qwuery is going to be a view, you should recreate the code. Views calling ciews are one of the causes of badly performing databases. They also are extremely painful to maintain and this peopel find it eaiser to add another view on top rather than go through the chain to determine which view needs to change. You can eventually end up joining to the same table 15 times and generating millions of records to get a result set of 3. I knwo this from painful expereince where application devloeprs though that this was a good idea. Do not ever use views to call views.

Comment: @HLGEM: Not every view calling a view is an issue from the performance point of view. Yes, those that result in a set of tables being self-joined multiple times, would likely cause performance problems, but I think that's where good planning (or, at least, proper analysis of existing codebase) should come into play too. When that (i.e. multiple self-joins) is not the case, nesting views is perfectly fine in terms of performance. (As for the issues arising from the nesting itself, I believe I've covered those in my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Do as you please.

The query optimizer will analyse the code and build the same execution plan.